# Permanently delete phishing tools in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, security, googlestrustedstore

My site was affected by guruincsite. I installed a backup, updated to the latest version of Magento and updated with all security packages. Also, I checked that nothing is referred to these tools or database files.

Google Safe Browsing the site has put me back as "not dangerous" but it still appears in the poster Google Chrome on dangerous place. As I read, I like McAfee continues to detect high-risk site. I hope you can guide me and help me because most do not.

The domain is as follows http://goo.gl/dSdniv

Comment: Good to see you've taken measures to bring your shop back to a secure state. I think the question is a bit off topic here though and you should contact McAfee and Google and issue a support requests regarding this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much and I am two weeks ago tried to remove everything related to phishing tools. How do I communicate with them so that I can provide help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the site by first applying patches

1) Apply all security patches

2) Then check for the script which is inserted by attackers

It will be in 2 places cms homepage and another in footer section of the site remove that script

3) Do check all the files for the script.

Remove from there and then fetch the site again

This will resolve issue for those whose site is infected by the attack.

Timely patches will prevent store for future attacks else you will again see the site having issue

Thanks

Comment: I have performed all steps outlined in the various guidance on this issue. I made a full backup of the site until a date that still, in principle, the site was not infected, and also went all Magento files to update again.

Comment: You will need to re-fetch whole site in Google Webmaster. Then it will remove your site from blacklist.